# ConTeXt - Make text embody figure and respect margins

Tags: graphics, floats, margins, context

I am trying rewrite an already formatted layout to ConTeXt, but I face two major problems. Please have a look at the goal I am aiming at and at the source code below.
I have tried many suggestions from various manuals and the wiki, however, there is no way I can format the layout as depicted. Having tried

 \startfiguretext, the text stays in it's narrow structure.

 \placefigure does allow me to place the bold text in the first line only if the text above is the picture.

 \starthangaround could work, but there is always an offset between the text area and the - invisible - frame. Not to mention, I do not get it it to the right hand side.
Either way, those paragraphs borders get violated easily, \hboxes are overfull constantly. Messing around with sloppypar or emergencystretch did not help. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.
Link to Layout:
http://www-user.tu-cottbus.de/~kitzmrob/desiredLayoutScreenshot.png

```
\enableregime   [utf-8]
\setuppapersize         [A5][]
\setuplayout[           height=middle,
                    location=middle,
                    backspace=2.0cm,            
                    leftmargin=1.5cm,           
                    leftmargindistance=0.25cm,
                    width=10.80cm,          
                    rightmargin=1.5cm,
                    rightmargindistance=0.25cm,
                    topspace=0.35cm,            
                    header=0.5cm,               
                    headerdistance=1.15cm,      
                    footer=0.5cm,
                    footerdistance=0.75cm,
                    bottomspace=0.75cm,
            ]

\starttext

\starthangaround {
    \framed         [%align=bottom, % unclear behavior
                    frame=on,       % visible for demonstration
                    width=.475\textwidth]
    {\externalfigure [amIaCow?] [width=.475\textwidth] 
    % \crlf
    % \placefloatcaption
    % [figure]
    % [ref:acow]
    % {undesiredCaption}
    }
}
{\bf Bold text \hfill Bold text}
\input montgomery
%\input davis
%\input zapf
%\input thuan
%\input knuth
%\input dawkins

\stophangaround

\stoptext
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you switch to mkiv you can try [``\starthanging[location=right]``](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics#Flow_text_around_a_picture) instead of the *hangaround* environment.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an MkIV solution (compile with `context`, instead of `texexec`). It uses the option `right` which pushes the float to the right of the
following paragraph, `none` removes the caption and `high` fixes the spacing.

Also see my [answer to the question Context: Placing float (figure) and text-top at same
height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58015/5245) for a related example.

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]  %% only for demonstration
\starttext

  \startplacefigure [location={right,none,high}]
    \externalfigure
  \stopplacefigure

  \startlinealignment [middle]
    \bold{Bold Text}\hfill\bold{Bold Text}
  \stoplinealignment

  \input montgomery

\stoptext
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, Marco. Using ConTeXt, I am not able to compile neither this example nor the other, really nice one, that you have provided. What is this [dum] all about?

Comment: It created the nice looking picture instead of a gray box, just eye-candy. Which version are you running? The example is MkIV only as I mentioned. If you already use MkIV try to replace the linealignment environment with a single `\midaligned{\bold{…}…\hfill…}` call since it's a rather new command.

Comment: I am using ConTeXt (LuaTex), editing in TeXworks

Comment: If you can't get it working we need to know your exact version? You can obtain it running the following document `\starttext\contextversion\stoptext`.

Comment: 2011.05.18 18:04
This is getting embarrasing for me now.. For my excuse: I am sitting at ol' university workstation.

Comment: You can install context minimals in a user directory.

Comment: Okay, I have reinstalled ConTeXt, Version is now 2013.03.29 01:03. Was successful to compile your nice files, but now I cannot use any editor anymore but have to use the terminal instead. Damn.

Comment: Run `source /path/to/setuptex` from the terminal and then launch the editor *from the terminal*.