# Context: Placing float (figure) and caption-top at same height on grid

Tags: captions, vertical-alignment, context, grid-typesetting

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58015/6819) explains very well how to get text on context's grid and floats to align nicely. I have the same requirement for aligning, but I need it for the caption beside the figure.

Considering the following example (adapted from the same answer) how could I get

- the caption to be on the top line of the grid?
- the figure's top to align with the x-height of the first grid line?

```

```
\useMPlibrary        [dum]
\setuplayout         [grid=yes]
\setupinterlinespace [line=20pt]

\setupfloats   [figure] [sidealign=line]
\setupcaptions [figure] [location={left, high},
%                        inbetween={\blank[-\strutdepth]}
                        ]

\starttext
\showgrid

\startplacefigure
  [title={There is not so much basic instruction, as of now, as there was in the old days, showing the differences between good and bad typographic design.},
  ]
\externalfigure [dummy] [width=.6\textwidth]
\stopplacefigure
\input zapf

\stoptext
```

```

Comment: Judging from the source there once seemed to be a mechanism `\setupfloatcaption[figure][location=grid]`, but it seems to be not implemented (anymore?) and the caption is just not displayed at all.

Comment: Thank you for going into depth with this! I had thought this might be solved by some simple instructions which I just couldn't figure out. But by what you found out it looks like I should take this problem to the developers.

Comment: Crosspost on ntg-context https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088502.html

Comment: oh yes, I should have mentioned that I have linked to this question on the mailing list to bring Henri's conclusion to the attention of the context-developers and/or possibly get hints for a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trial-and-error I've come to the following that works for my documents. It seems a bit hacky to me -- I think there should be a way to put all grid-handling in the preamble -- but it meets my requirements for the result.

Without the `offset`, the picture aligns to the top of the text box, not of the actual ascender height. The length has to be adjusted to fit the font and spacing.

```
\useMPlibrary        [dum]
\setuplayout         [grid=yes]
\setupinterlinespace [line=20pt]


\setupcaption [figure] [
                        location={left,high}, 
                        number=no,
                        inbetween={\blank[-.01mm]}, %picture top-aligned, caption on grid
                        ]


\starttext


\showgrid


\startplacefigure
    [location=top,none,title={There is not so much basic instruction, as of now, as there was
    in the old days, showing the differences between good and bad typographic design.},
    ]
  \placeongrid[max]{\offset[y=2mm]{
  \externalfigure [dummy] [width=.6\textwidth]%
  }}
\stopplacefigure

\input zapf


\stoptext
```